# Apache reverse proxy mTLS only between client and proxy, regular TLS between proxy and backends

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, mod-ssl, mtls

am trying to create an apache reverse proxy (for webservices) where i need Imutual authentication (mTLS) between clients and the proxy itself, but i don't need mTLS between the proxy & the backends (multiple backends runnings multiple webservices on different ports), regular SSL is sufficient.

a schema of what i am trying to achieve :

[image: schema1]

I was thinking of an apache configuration that would look like the one below  but my apache knowledge is very limited and i'd like advices.

Note : The configuration below is only showing 1 vHost (not the whole apache config), as i plan to have as much vHosts as Webservices i have in the backend (as this is going to serve multiple applications) :

```
# ---------------------------------------------
# mTLS vHost for Service <Appl_a>
# ---------------------------------------------
<VirtualHost <dns_alias>:<PortID>

 ServerName <dns_alias>
  
    # Custom logs for this vHost
    ErrorLog "<Logdir>/error_log"
    TransferLog "<Logdir>/access_log"
    
    # SSL activation on the proxy itself
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "<Path_to_keys>/proxy.cer"        # Proxy cert file + CA trust cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "<Path_to_keys>/proxy.key"     # Proxy private key 
    
    # security options
    ProxyRequests off                    # only a reverse proxy
    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3   # we only allow TLS 1.2 et 1.3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On               # server forces ciphers (not the client)
    
    # client certificate authentication (for mTLS between proxy & client)
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile "<Path_to_keys>/client.cer"    # Client's certificate file or CA only ? (as they are both signed by the same CA) ?
    
    # I BELIEVE I DONT NEED THIS
    # as it would only be if i wanted mTLS between proxy and backend 
    # (or to forward client certs to the backend, can you please confirm ?)
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile "<Path_to_keys>/server.cer" 
    SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "<Path to keys>/proxy.pem"
    SSLProxyVerify require
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
 
    # Proxy
    RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT ""   # I BELIEVE this is also useless
    <Location />
       RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_CERT "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s" # USELESS ? as this is to forward the client cert to the backend, but i don't need mTLS to reach backends ?
       ProxyPass https://<appl_URL>:<appl_PORT>/<WS_URL>         
       ProxyPassReverse ttps://<appl_URL>:<appl_PORT>/<WS_URL>
    </Location>
    
 </VirtualHost>

# ---------------------------------------------
# mTLS vHost for Service <n>
# ---------------------------------------------
... same for another port/ws
```

1. Could you please help me confirm if this configuration makes sense or how would you do such a thing.
   Multiple parts in this config are, i believe, useless as they are meant to forward client certificates to the backend for a full mutual authentication proxy (which is not what i want) - see comments in the config.
2. Second thing : what if i wanted to terminate the traffic at the proxy level and forward the requests to the backends as HTTP. Should i simply replace https by http in the Proxy & ProxyPassReverse directives ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For point 1:**

In the appropiate virtualhost you just need two extra directives and a optional one.

A directive to tell Apache which CA's to authorize for client certificates (this is a list of root CA for client certificates you admit):

```
SSLCACertificateFile "/path/to/ca-auth-list.pem"
```

Then in each path you want mTLS to happen or the whole virtualhost if you want:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

An extra to define which depth or amount of CA in the chain you support:

```
SSLVerifyDepth 2
```

**For point 2:**

Reverse proxy connections are something else entirely of what the client sends to the server, so backend for the proxy can be https/http/ajp/ws or whatever you may need.

PS: ***Do not use Location for proxypass directives***, ProxyPass already provides a location in its first parameters but location and proxypass directives an interpreted in opposide ways, so mix them is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: thank you for your answer. we will make some tests soon and i will let you know if it worked (and mark the question as answered). so you confirm that none of the SSLProxy* options are required in my setup ? (i can get rid of them), as well as the RequestHeader ones